# Is it possible to permanently disable html buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm new to programming so I don't know much, but I was wondering if there is a way to permanently disable a button. I've used this:

```
document.getElementById("WhateverTheIdIs").disabled = true;
```

but at some parts of the document I reverse that by using this:

```
document.getElementById("WhateverTheIdIs").disabled = false;
```

I need something that can override that, and just permanently disable the button. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That's not your problem.  The problem is the design.

Comment: OK... so what do I do to fix it?

Comment: _"but at some parts of the document I reverse that"_. So don't do that.

Comment: @user3130551: Get a time machine, go grab your future self, drag him to now, show him your design, and watch him cringe.  Worked for me.

Comment: I need to reverse all of them, but I need to reverse all of the buttons. But if it gets into certain if statements, I need to permanently disable the button, but if it didn't make it into the if statement, I need that to enable every button

Comment: What j08691 says is basically agreeable. If you're rather looking for an overengineered solution, you could use a class name or a `data-` attribute to mark buttons that shouldn't be enabled. Then write a wrapper for disabling buttons, which checks if the attribute is set, and if so, refuses to take action.

Comment: Frits van Campen, I don't get what you mean at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to disable or enable a button.  So, if you're looking for a separate way to permanently disable a button (yet leave it visible) that will override setting `.disabled` to true - there is no such property or feature for a button.

There are many ways to fix your code.  For example, when you want to permanently disable a button, you can set a custom attribute on the button and then everywhere you think about enabling the button, you can just check that custom attribute and if it's set, don't enable the button.

Other options you could consider are hiding the button or removing the button from the DOM.

You can fix your code by making your own permanent disable in your own code.  If, rather than manipulating the `.disabled` property directly, you just switch to using these functions, then your code would respect the `.permDisabled` property.

```
function getElem(elem) {
    if (typeof elem === "string") {
        elem = document.getElementById(elem);
    }
    return elem;
}

function disableButtonPermanent(elem) {
    elem = getElem(elem);
    elem.disabled = true;
    elem.permDisabled = true;
}

function disableButton(elem) {
    elem = getElem(elem);
    elem.disabled = true;
}

function enableButton(elem) {
    elem = getElem(elem);
    if (!elem.permDisabled) {
        elem.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to push too much logic into the DOM. This is *very* bad practise. Make sure your data model matches that what you're modelling. Have a boolean: `all_buttons_are_disabled` and then a boolean `button_X_is_disabled` then do something like:

```
function updateButtonX() {
    document.getElementById("WhateverTheIdIs").disabled =
      all_buttons_are_disabled || button_X_is_disabled;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3n3w3/

`toggleX` will disable/enabled `buttonX`, but when you press `disable all` all buttons are permanently disabled.

Comment: s/login/logic? Wasn't sure.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: ButtonX being disabled is a result of two things: all buttons are disabled, or buttonX is disabled. Model these aspects separately. Don't try to push it into the HTML's disabled property because you can't distinguish between these cases.

Comment: As I said earlier, I'm new to programming, and I am really confused

Comment: This is kind of embarrassing, but I just thought of an idea that's completely unrelated to what you said, but thanks for trying to help.